# Read contents from text file, copy it, and put in a new text file. C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, text, io

This shouldn't even be this difficult but for some reason windows is only creating the output "text2.txt" which is blank. text.txt is a real file with real text contents but it is not being transferred over. Please help me figure this out.

Thank you.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    ifstream stream1("D:\\tests\\test1\\text.txt");
    ofstream stream2("D:\\tests\\test2\\text2.txt");
    stream2 << stream1.rdbuf();

    stream1.close();
    stream2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Running the test program, with only the filenames changed, produced the expected results for me. I see nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: ... other than a lack of error checking.

Comment: Very strange, the contents were copied over?

Comment: Perfectly copied over.

Comment: Well then...very strange...Not seeing this.

Comment: Does a `stream2.flush()` prior to closing make a difference?

Comment: close() does an automatic flush(). This has always been the case.

Comment: Have you tried testing `stream1` for errors?  Perhaps the file is open in a text editor and locked.  Does `stream1.is_open()` return true?  What happens if you do something simple like `for( string s; getline( stream1, s ); ) cout << s << endl;`?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because the file "text.txt" has been already owned by other process with a particular file share mode or something.

Check it out with GetLastError() or the @err pseudo-register as follows.

```
ifstream stream1("D:\\tests\\test1\\text.txt");
DWORD code = GetLastError();
```

Or

[image: @err pseudo-register]

You may get the error code: 0x20. This is the most usual case where we fail to access a file. For more details about file share mode, see this: [MSDN CreateFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=KO-KR&k=k(%22WINBASE%2FCREATEFILE%22);k(CREATEFILE);k(DevLang-%22C%2B%2B%22);k(TargetOS-WINDOWS)&rd=true)

In addition, please always make sure that you put check code after opening a file so that you can tell the file can be accessed as follows.

```
ifstream stream1("D:\\tests\\test1\\text.txt");
if ( !stream1.is_open() )
{
    // ...
}
```

Hopefully that is the case you got and this answer is helpful. :)